# Will a Linux NTP server with an upstream Windows time source have any less jitter?

Tags: linux, windows, ntp, jitter

For my infrastructure we have a platform which cannot synchronize over NTP to a W32time service due to too much jitter from the Windows time source.

So my question is, if we have a W32time source upstream to a Linux NTP server, will referring to the Linux NTP time service normalize or decrease the amount of jitter in the time provided?

Comment: Is the Windows time source running on a physical or a virtual machine?

Comment: It is a physical Windows server 2008 domain controller.